# How to change color of table row dynamically without _rowVariant?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm using a bootstrap-vue table to display infos I'm retrieving from a JSON. One info I'm receiving is an int named "Status", I want to change the color of the entire row according to this variable, e.g, if Status is equal to 1, then row is green. ]

In the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/) of bootstrap-vue it shows the row changing color according to a _rowVariant object inside each element in the item array data, but how can I change the color of my row without having this object in my items array? If not possible, how can I insert this variable into every object of my array?

Here's the code regarding the table content:

```
<b-container fluid>
  <b-table hover :items="requests" :fields="fields"
  @row-clicked="onRowClicked"
  >

  <template slot="show_details" slot-scope="row">
  <!-- we use @click.stop here to prevent emitting of a 'row-clicked' event  -->
  <b-button size="sm" @click.stop="row.toggleDetails" class="mr-2">
   {{ row.detailsShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Details
  </b-button>
  </template>
  <template slot="row-details" slot-scope="row">
    <b-card>
      <b-row class="mb-2">
        <b-col sm="3" class="text-sm-right"><b>Info 1:</b></b-col>
        <b-col>{{ row.item.horas_info }}</b-col>
      </b-row>
      <b-row class="mb-2">
        <b-col sm="3" class="text-sm-right"><b>Info 2:</b></b-col>
        <b-col>{{ row.item.pdf }}</b-col>
      </b-row>
      <b-button size="sm" @click="row.toggleDetails">Hide Details</b-button>
    </b-card>
  </template>
  </b-table>
</b-container>
```

Comment: [https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use computed properties to add extra field to item list:

```
computed: {
  formartedItems () {
    if (!this.requests) return []
    return this.requests.map(item => {
      item._rowVariant  = this.getVariant(item.Status)
      return item
    })
  }
},
methods: {
  getVariant (status) {
    switch (status) {
      case 1:
        return 'success'
      case 1:
        return 'danger'
      default:
        return 'active'
    }
  }
}
```

then in HTML code:

```
<b-table hover :items="formartedItems" :fields="fields" @row-clicked="onRowClicked">
...
</b-table>
```

If you want more customized style, you can check `tdClass`, `thClass` or `thStyle` in bootstrap-vue table.

Answer (score 5):

Add `:tbody-tr-class="rowClass"` in `<b-table :tbody-tr-class="rowClass"></table>` tag and add `rowClass` to methods:

```
methods: {
  rowClass(item, type) {
    if (!item || type !== 'row') return
    if (item.user_id == this.$auth.user.id) return 'table-success'
  }
}
```